# Do packages harm flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using too many packages in my flutter application, isn't a good thing to do so? do many packages harm the application's performance?

Comment: I don't have a proof on that but from my experience using many packages that it doesn't have an effect if your code is written properly

Comment: I actually use all of them, but there are some alternatives that may be used instead of a package, so is it a good idea to stick with the package or prevent using it would be better?

Comment: I told you I use alot of packages and there doesn't seem to be performance issues, and with that in mind, why not use a package if it makes your life easier and saves you from writing bunch of boilerplate code

Comment: Okay, thanks for your response :)

Comment: If the packages you import have a lot of code that can't be tree-shaken away (e.g. code in the package is very interconnected), then it can impact the size of your binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking over the web I couldn't find a single article that talks about this issue, not even the flutter documentation.

But on their section about optimizing the app, the flutter team says about reducing app size(which can also affect performance obviously):

> Some of the other things you can do to make your app smaller are:
>
> Remove unused resources
>
> Minimize resource imported from libraries
>
> Support a limited number of screen densities
>
> Compress PNG and JPEG files

looking at :

> Remove unused resources
>
> Minimize resource imported from libraries

You can conclude that inclding packages does not mainly hurt performance, but importing alot of resources from these packages into your file and not using them effeciently can hurt it (look at @jamesdlin 's comment:to understand why is that (its about tree shaking process)

> If the packages you import have a lot of code that can't be
> tree-shaken away (e.g. code in the package is very interconnected),
> then it can impact the size of your binary.

And as a final note, from my usage of flutter and often usage of alot of packages in my apps (to save alot of boilerplate), I can't say that I notice any performance issues due to many packages being present in my app